# How to present points on axes in Matlab

Tags: matlab, axes

I have two vectors of the same length and I'd like to treat the first as X values and the second as Y values and present (x,y) points on a graph.

How do I do this simple thing in Matlab?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that it is just [plot(x, y)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html) what you need.

For example to plot 'dots' use `plot(x, y, '.')`. For more examples of markers to use, see the attached link.

Comment: It creates a line and I would like to see just the points. Do you know how I should do that? Thanks once again :)!!!